# How do I run the VBA msi installer dependencies based on install options using WiX?

Tags: vba, wix

I am in the process of creating a new WiX 3.x installer project for our older integration product that depends on the VBA SDK in Visual Studio 2017.

Our product currently uses an extremely outdated InstallShield project that I've determined isn't really salvageable and selected WiX for various reasons. One of the many reasons is that (Unlike the VBA 6.3 Redist) the VBA 7.1 redistributables do not come with any installation wrapper and the SDK only includes some VS2010 project code written in C to generate a setup.exe file.

Originally I was going to convert/re-write the C code to C# and create a custom action. Then as I heard about Burn.exe I thought that may be an option, but it seems that does not have the ability to act dynamically based off installer dialog options from my main install project. (Am I wrong here?)

Ideally, I wish there were merge modules for the VBA 7.1 runtimes. However, since MS stopped offering new SDK licenses years ago (we're grandfathered in) all developer support for the SDK has disappeared from their site. All my searching for a merge module set has been futile.

So for VBA 7.1, I have a main MSI and a dozen or so optional MSI packages depending on environment and localization.

How best should I incorporate these into an installer package for our integration product with the prerequisites mentioned above?

Comment: Exactly what are the requirements for installing those MSI packages? Do they have to be defined by the users, or would you be able to automatically calculate what is correct packages to install based on the environment at the installer's runtime? You might want to look at [WixSharp](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp) if you'd rather customize the actions you want to perform.

Comment: Depending on the customization of features and other options during the UI portion of the install, I will need to adjust which MSI packages are installed.

Comment: I suspect you might need to use WixSharp then. As noted, WiX is declarative-based which is difficult to work with when you need to support user interaction or complex environment checks at install time.